# Linux Bash ... If time > 20:00 then echo 'hello' fi

Tags: linux, bash

I'm very very new to Linux Bash and I'm not sure if what I want to do can be achieved.

I have a program that runs 24/7 uploading one of my servers to the cloud. The only problem is, it is killing my bandwidth.

So my idea is to let it run from 00:05 to 05:55 , no one will be busy at this time of night.

So something like:

```
If $(date +"%T") < 05:55 then

backup.sh

else 

killbackup.sh

fi
```

Comment: why don't you just use a cron-script?

Comment: I suppose I could use cron to run the killbackup.sh scrip every 5min from 06:00 to 00:00 and the backup.sh every 5min from 00:05 to 05:55. if I don't find an answer I will look at doing than. I apologise for the late reply have been extremely busy the past few days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

h=$(date +"%k")    # current hour (24h) without leading zero
m=$(date +"%M")    # current minute
t=$[h*60+m]        # calculate minutes since midnight

# -gt: greater-than, -lt: less-than
if [[ $t -gt 5 ]] && [[ $t -lt 355 ]]; then
  # run from 0:06 to 5:54
  backup.sh
else
  # run from 5:55 to 0:05
  killbackup.sh
fi
```

Comment: Hi Thanks , that's awesome. very cleaver way of doing it. counting the minutes since 00:00. have tested it 100% but looks like its working. thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
time=$(date +%T)
time=${time//:/}
if (( time < 055500 && time > 000500 ));then #between 00:05 to 05:55
    backup.sh
else
    killbackup.sh
fi
```

Comment: Hi Thanks , that's awesome. like how with this your timer can be second based.

Comment: @Chewy "like how with this your timer can be second based", if it's  a question, can you be more specific? I don't understand what you mean.... For clarification, in `time < 055500` the 05 part is the hour, 55 is the minute, and 00 is the second, you can specify the conditions with seconds as well...

Comment: Hi Jahid. Sorry there is no question I was saying, I like how you can use seconds in your code. E.G if you wanted the time to be 05:55:30 vs. 05:55:00 (For what ever reason you needed the extra 30 seconds) you could make it 055530.